# How to access IIS deployed asp.net application from remote systems

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have deployed an asp.net(2.0) application in IIS. I am able to access the link for the application from my system. How ever it is not accessible from the other systems in the same LAN.

What might be the problem?

Comment: What happens when you try to open the site in a browser?  Also, this probably belongs on serverfault.com, but it will be moved automatically if so, no need to repost.

Comment: If I open in my system then application is opened and if I try to open from other system(browser) then "Page cannot be displayed" message is shown.

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked your OS to make sure that it doesn't have any firewalls turned on?  That'd be the first thing that comes to mind on this.

To add an opening for port 80 in the windows firewall on your machine, run the following from an elevated command window.

```
netsh firewall add portopening protocol=tcp port=80 name=HTTP
```

If you're running a 3rd party firewall, you'd want to consult the documenation on that to do the same thing.  Just open port 80 for your machine, don't disable the whole firewall.

Comment: can you tell me how to do this?